Adding circuits to service disconnect panel
Is it code-compliant and safe to add 2 single pole breakers for 15A GFCI and 30A RV hook up circuits to this service disconnect panel? I opened the panel and pulled wires in expecting separate ground and neutral busses. When i realized ground and neutral were tied together on a single bus i stopped.
The double pole breaker is for a mini-split HVAC system installed before i bought the house. I am going to replace the romex with THHN for the 15A GFCI.




It's normal and customary for the main (first) panel to have ground and neutral sharing the neutral bus, as the (one, singular) neutral-ground bond is there.
If all other panels are wired as sub-panels with separate ground and neutral wires and no bond, then all is as it should be.
It's nearly all dual-rated at this time, (THHN & THWN) but you do need THWN (or XHHW, or some other wire coded with a W) to run in outside conduit that is defined as a wet location (and usually meets the definition.) NM/B (Romex) is, of course, totally unacceptable there.
